# Javascript : validating input must be filled if checkbox are checked

Tags: javascript, html

I have this html

```
<div class="form-row">
    <label for="form-check">Test</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="form-check" value="Agree" id="form-1">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Reason" name="reason">
</div>
```

My question is how do I validate if the checkbox is checked, the reason field must be filled?

Comment: it is not clear what you want. give more explanation, pls

Comment: Check this js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/y5jo90za/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the input fields checked property. When its checked then set the required property of the reason input field to true when not then set it's required property to false as in the example below.

*Note:* To show the behavior I have wrapped your input blocks inside a `<form>`

```js
let x = document.getElementById('form-1').addEventListener('click', function() {
  let x = document.getElementById('form-1').checked;
  console.log(x);
  if (x) {
    document.getElementById('reason').required = true;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('reason').required = false;
  }

  console.log("Is required? " + document.getElementById('reason').required);
});
```

```html
<div class="form-row">
  <form action="/action_page.php">

    <label for="form-check">Test</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="form-check" value="Agree" id="form-1">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Reason" name="reason" id="reason">
  </form>

</div>
```